# Laravel 7 adding custom Auth: admin url redirection when attempting to log in

Tags: php, laravel, exception

Am trying to redirect my new admin auth back to the url "/admin/login" and not the default laravel page with url"/login" upon the admin failling to login to the admin.
This is the code i was following and its not working as expected with no error but just returning to the default login.The admin should be able to enter the url "/admin" to login in and not this url "admin/login"

#### Handler.php

```
 <?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
 
public function report(Throwable $exception)
{
    parent::report($exception);
}

/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Throwable  $exception
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 *
 * @throws \Throwable
 */
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    
    $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);
    switch ($guard){
        case 'admin';
        $login = 'admin.login';
    break;
    case 'default';
    $login = 'login';
break;
    }
    return redirect()->guest(route($login));

    

}
```

}

#### auth.php The guard for admin

```
 <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
            
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Comment: what are you routes and what controllers are they pointing to for your special login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it to work by using the following code

#### Handler.php

```
   <?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;
use Exception;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr; //For arr:get()


class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
 */
protected $dontFlash = [
    'password',
    'password_confirmation',
];

/**
 * Report or log an exception.
 *
 * @param  \Throwable  $exception
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function report(Throwable $exception)
{
    parent::report($exception);
}

/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Throwable  $exception
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 *
 * @throws \Throwable
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
  if ($request->expectsJson())
  {
      return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.',401]);
  }

  $guard = Arr::get($exception->guards(), 0);

  switch ($guard)
  {
      case 'admin':
        $login = 'admin.login';
      break;

      default:
      $login = 'login';
    break;
  }
  return redirect()->guest(route($login));
}
```

}